# Deploying Django project with custom apps to heroku: remote: ERROR: /path/to/myapp/django-myapp is not a valid editable requirement

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am using Django 3.2

I have written a number of standalone apps, which I am using in my project. In my requirements file, I have included them at the bottom of the requirements.txt file like this:

#### requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.0
Babel==2.9.1
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
coverage==6.4.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2
django-appconf==1.0.5
django-crispy-forms==1.14.0
django-js-asset==2.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
python-decouple==3.6
pytz==2022.1
requests==2.27.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.9
webencodings==0.5.1
whitenoise==6.0.0

-e /path/to/django-apps/moderation/django-moderation
-e /path/to/django-apps/social/django-social
-e /path/to/django-apps/user/django-userprofile
-e /path/to/django-apps/event/django-events
-e /path/to/django-apps/contactus/django-contactus
```

On my local machine, I type: `pip install -r requirements.txt` and everything is installed correctly.

However, when I try to deploy to heroku by typing:

> git push heroku main

I get the following error message:

```
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        ERROR: /path/to/django-apps/moderation/django-moderation is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

How do I fix this, so I can push local changes to heroku?

Comment: hi I think its a problem because you use a local path and in Haruko cant access the path, so change the path to a relative path

Comment: I guess you mean a relative path to the project - and presumably, check the standalone apps into the git repository too?

Comment: Did you try enter the heroku bash and run `pip install` there?

Answer (score 1):

What you should be able to do is to install the standalone apps as git repositories and host them on GitHub. If you still want to have nicer commits, you can make a clone of the repository and use it instead.

Related information could be found in the below link:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#git-backed-distributions

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, but I'm still having problems. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72749409/pip-installing-from-github-requirements-txt-file-and-cli)